# Getting certain td's to swap places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the effect of certain td's(not all) different tr's to swap places with the ones directly above or below them. I only want the last 3 td's not the entire row. I seem to have trouble finding something that will do JUST the 3 td's I want, not the entire row.

You can see the example I have set up here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwHbz

I know you can do something like :

```
$("#Row1").after($("#Row2"));
```

However I dont want the entire row. So if I clicked .saTableDown on the first row that has it, I would want the Target, Level, and instruction to swap with the ones below it, and so on. Ir something like this possible in jquery/javascript? I can't seem to figure it out if so. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEJxH

I would find the index of the `tr` you have clicked up/down, and if it is not the first/last, swap it with the previous/next `tr`. Then swap the numbers back around. I have given the number td a class of `.num`, and the target td a class of `.target`, I assume you have access to the markup to be able to do that.

jQuery:

```
$('.saTableUp').click(function(){
    //find the index of the parent tr
    var parentTr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var index = parentTr.index();

    // if not the first element
    if (index > 1) {
      var parentSwap = parentTr.prev();
      //swap rows
      parentSwap.before(parentTr);
      // move one number up a row
      parentTr.children('.num').before(parentSwap.children('.num'));
      // move other number (now the second .num in the row) down a row
      parentSwap.children('.target').before(parentTr.children('.num:eq(1)'));
    }
});

$('.saTableDown').click(function(){
    //find the index of the parent tr
    var parentTr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var index = parentTr.index();

    // if not the last element
    if (index < 4) {
      var parentSwap = parentTr.next();
      //swap rows
      parentSwap.after(parentTr);
      // move one number down a row
      parentTr.children('.num').before(parentSwap.children('.num'));
      // move other number (now the second .num in the row) up a row
      parentSwap.children('.target').before(parentTr.children('.num:eq(1)'));
    }
});
```

Comment: On rereading your question I think my answer isn't exactly what you want. Is it just that you want the numbers (1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04) to always stay in that order?

Comment: You are correct, this is good, except i want the numbers to stay (so the last 3 td's would move only). thank you!

Comment: Ok, I've edited my CodePen and my answer. I hope that's what you wanted now!